# ul not moving to the right

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why does this list not move to the topright of the screen?

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

li { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I don't know why float:right; doesn't fix this

Comment: Who says it doesn't ..? https://jsfiddle.net/szavpx5k/ -> you need to provide us with a proper [mre] of your issue, not just a tiny snippet of CSS that lacks all context.

Comment: FYI: The computed value of `float` automatically becomes `none`, when the element is absolute positioned - so that combination you got there does not make much sense to begin with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because by default the `ul` is 100% wide, so `float:right` has no visible effect on it since it fills the whole width of the container. The `li`s are left-aligned inside the `ul`.

You can add a `width` setting to the `ul` (i.e. 50%, or a fixed pixel value), then you'll see the effect of the `float:right`.

Answer (score 0):

I make it work with this:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
        
li { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

(removed the float right)

Make sure that you include your styles on the page. For example, check if your list has dots before every item and if is it inlined or one under another.

If you have dots before every item and the items are one under another you probably didn't include your CSS file correctly.

If you think you're including your styles correctly you can check on which level you added the ul element. If you have nested it in a few other elements I suggest you get it out as you want to put it on the very top right of the page.